# How can I download the latest version of the GPU computing SDK?

Tags: cuda

I want to download the latest version of the GPU computing SDK which is compatible with the system that I work on. The CUDA driver and runtime version are 4.10, but I can not find the link. I can just find the CUDA Toolkit which is not what I want. Can anyone help me by sending a direct link for me? Thanks.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278687/where-to-download-cuda-sdk-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA 4.1 is the latest CUDA release. The GPU Computing SDK for this release can be found at the bottom of this page: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-41

The GPU Computing SDK is supposed to be available at this page: http://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-sdk
But, it looks like NVIDIA has messed up the webpages a bit, the CUDA Toolkit and the GPU Computing SDK pages point at each other, with neither offering the SDK.