# Where to download CUDA SDK from

Tags: sdk, cuda, nvidia

I have been searching the nvidia website for the GPU Computing SDK as I am trying to build the pointclouds library (PCL) with cuda support. However, on the nvidia website all I can find are links for the toolkit and not a single download link for the SDK.

I found this post: [How can I download the latest version of the GPU computing SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872896/how-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-the-gpu-computing-sdk)

However, that solution seems outdated and does not seem to work.

Comment: Just to let you know, the SDK is now part of the CUDA Toolkit, see [https://developer.nvidia.com/accelerated-computing-developer-program-home](https://developer.nvidia.com/accelerated-computing-developer-program-home)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The link that fritzone gave (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) is an installer package that includes the CUDA toolkit, developer drivers, and the SDK. Since CUDA 4.2, NVidia has distributed all of these together in a single package. Older versions of CUDA still have them as separate downloads and are available from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive.

Answer (score 2):

Try: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
and select your architecture/OS

Answer (score 0):

I think adding GPU support for other libs requires only the CUDA toolkit in most cases, which can be found publicly.

There is also a CUDA Compiler SDK.

It is located in the Registered Developers Website.

First, you have to register as a registered developer by [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/user/register).

After login, apply for the [CUDA/GPU Computing Registered Developer Program](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cuda-registered-developer-program)

Then you can see the download link of CUDA Compiler SDK.